# Xcode project git repo contains changes of another git repo in commit dialog

Tags: xcode, git, xcode9.1

I have 2 Xcode projects both separate git repos, here is how the 2 project folders reside:

```
desktop/project1
desktop/somefolder/project2
```

While working with `project1`, I dragged a sub-directory from `project2` to use in `project1`, this caused something terrible in `project1`, when I want to Xcode>commit it contains uncommitted changes from `project2`'s repo.

I tried looking for `.gitmodules` file in project1, but there isn't one.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing Xcode derived data from `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData` fixed this issue.

Dragging files/folders across projects is a common action and I never faced this issue before, I believe its a bug in Xcode 9, filed a bug report.